Is a Moon Touched weapon considered magical for purposes of overcoming resistance vs non-magical damage?
I've never seen this specifically addressed, besides a lot of opinions on Reddit threads and the like.
Moon Touched only says: In darkness, the unsheathed blade of this sword sheds moonlight, creating bright light in a 15-foot radius and dim light for an additional 15 feet.
But it is included in the list of Common Magic Items, so is it magical for overcoming a creature's resistance vs bludgeoning/piercing/slashing damage from non-magical weapons?

Related: Does this constitute a magical weapon for the purpose of overcoming resistance?

I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it is answered by the more general question linked in the duplicate banner.

I am reversing this closure because I don't think the cited question is a duplicate. The question you've cited, while relevant, refers to a DM created home brew weapon and both answers generally include a deference to DM adjudication. However, a Moon Touched is an official weapon whose categorization of being magical is less debatable.

Yes, a Moon-Touched Sword is a magic item, and therefore a magical attack.
If you look at the Monster Manual introduction, there's a section on Vulnerabilities, Resistances, and Immunities that mentions

Particular creatures are even resistant or immune to damage from non-magical attacks (a magical attack is an attack delivered by a spell, a magic item, or another magical source)

emphasis mine
In the general case, a weapon just simply needs to be a magic item to overcome resistance to nonmagical attacks.
There is no requirement for a magical bonus to attack or damage. For example, a Moon-Touched Sword or a Weapon of Warning would overcome resistance to non-magical attacks, even though neither provide any magical bonuses to attack or damage.
The attunement conundrum
According to the Basic Rules, Chapter 14: Attunement

Without becoming attuned to an item that requires attunement, a creature gains only its nonmagical benefits, unless its description states otherwise.

emphasis mine
However, it should be noted, Jeremy Crawford answered this question

does a magic weapon still bypass resistance or immunity to nonmagical attacks if it requires attunement and the wielder isn't attuned?

With

You can strike someone with a magic weapon even if you're not attuned to it, and the weapon still counts as magical. Your attunement doesn't determine its magicalness.

While designers public statements are advice, not official rulings, they are often used to support rulings.
At first glance, this may seem contradictory: if a creature does not gain the magical benefits of an item without attunement, how can a non-attuned magic weapon still bypass resistances? The key lies in understanding that the concepts of "magical benefits" and "magical status" are distinct. A weapon's ability to overcome resistance to nonmagical attacks is inherent to its magical status, which remains intact regardless of attunement. In contrast, attunement specifically pertains to accessing the additional magical benefits of that weapon, which are not available until attuned.
In summary, a magic weapon maintains its magical status and its capacity to bypass resistances without requiring attunement, while the wielder must still attune to unlock its full range of magical benefits.
I may just be erring on the side of congruency, as while some agree with this presumption, others have come to a different conclusion.
There is at least one exception, even if attunement status doesn't impact magical status
The Moonblade (different from a Moon-Touched Sword) is special
as while it is a sentient magic item, it does have this special trait,

It functions like a normal longsword until a worthy soul finds it and lays claim to its power.

This is a case of a specific exception, where an otherwise magical weapon functions like a normal longsword. In this case, the weapon would not overcome resistance to nonmagical attacks.
However, once attuned, it would indeed be magical as it would lose this special trait and overcome resistance to nonmagical attacks.

You might choose to expand this answer to cover using non-weapin magic items as improvised weapons, and using a magic weapon in an improvised way. For example, if you bash someone over the head with a charged Tome of Clear Thought, is that considered a magic attack because the book is magical at the time? Presumably a used Tome doesn't count as magical while it is recharging (or does it?). Alternately, if you bash someone over the head with the pommel of your Vorpal Sword, would that be a magical attack?

Your exception is not really an exception at all, according to rules about attuning every magic item that character is not attuned to act as a mundane item and as such it is considered not magical until attuned.

@ArekKubiński That's not true: Does a magic weapon still bypass resistance to nonmagical attacks if it requires attunement and the wielder isn’t attuned?

@matszwecja Good to know, thanks for linking source.

@matszwecja I'm not sure that's "settled" even with a designer comment. I'll update answer to include the seemingly contradictory statements.
